# Allow checkout only when a product of a mandatory category is in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I'd like to stop any customer advancing to the checkout if they do not have a particular product category in their basket. I would also like to tell them with an error message that they need to add a certain product. I've found some code but cannot it to work. I've added it as a code snippet into my Wordpress install but alas it does not function and there are no error messages even though I have debugging switched on. Here is the code that I have found in Github that may need modification in order for this to work:

```
function sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {

    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $category = 'sibling';

    // get the product category
    $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );

    // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
    if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $category_name = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category, 'product_cat' ) . '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';

    // check if this category is the only thing in the cart
    if ( sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {

        // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Hi there! Looks like your cart only contains products from the %1$s category &ndash; you must purchase a product from another category to check out.', $category_name ), 'error' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'sv_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );

/**
 * Checks if a cart contains exclusively products in a given category
 * 
 * @param string $category the slug of the product category
 * @return bool - true if the cart only contains the given category
 */
function sv_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {

    // check each cart item for our category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
        if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
    return true;
}
```

So I'm looking to stop checkout (with error message) if the 'sibling' category is the only item in the cart. I have a 'standard' category which must be in the basket before the customer makes it to the checkout. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have a solution that will make the trick. There is especially 2 main functions *(the last ones)*:

1. The first function *(N°3)* display your message on cart page, when there is something in cart but not the mandatory product category. Displays also the message on the mandatory product archive pages *(useful when customer get redirected from checkout, see below)*.
2. The second function *(N°4)* redirect customer to the product mandatory category archive pages when it tries to checkout and his cart has not that missing mandatory product category.

> Define before your mandatory category slug in **`your_mandatory_category_slug()`** function.

This is the code:

```
// Function that define the mandatory product category
 function your_mandatory_category_slug(){

     // DEFINE HERE the SLUG of the needed product category
    $category = 'clothing';
    return $category;
 }


// Conditional function that returns true if the mandatory product category is in cart
function has_mandatory_category(){
    $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
    $has_cat = false;

    // Iterrating each item in cart and detecting…
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {

        // Detects if the needed product category is in cart items
        if ( has_term($category_needed, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $has_cat = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $has_cat;
 }


// Function that display a message if there is not in cart a mandatory product category
function mandatory_category_display_message() {
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();

    // check that cart is not empty (for cart and product category archives)
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( $category_needed ) ) ){
        $category_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_needed, 'product_cat' );
        if ( is_wp_error( $category_obj ) ) return;

        // Display message when product category is not in cart items
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() ) {
            $category_name = $category_obj->name;
            $category_url = get_term_link( $category_needed, 'product_cat' );

            // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '<strong>Reminder:</strong> You have to add in your cart, a product from "%1$s" category, to be allowed to check out. Please return <a href="%2$s"> here to "%1$s" product page</a>', 'your_theme_domain'), $category_name, $category_url ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mandatory_category_display_message', 30 ); // for product mandatory category archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_category_display_message' ); // for cat page


// Function that redirect from checkout to mandatory product category archives pages
function mandatory_category_checkout_redirect() {

    // If cart is not empty on checkout page
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_checkout() ){
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();

        // If missing product category => redirect to the products category page
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() )
            wp_redirect( get_term_link( $category_needed, 'product_cat' ) );
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mandatory_category_checkout_redirect');
```

*This goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and fully functional.

Comment: Loic! Fantastic! It works a treat. Thank you so much.

Comment: Works like a charm for my Wordpress installation with Woocommerce v2.6.12.

I would like to add two mandatory product-categories, maybe 3 or 4 in the future. I tried changing:

**$category = 'slug1';**
to

**$category = 'slug1', 'slug2';**
and

**$category = array('slug1','slug2');**
Without success. Is there a way to make this code work with multiple slugs?

Comment: @ResulCimen You should ask a new question with your requirements… then notify me here with the link.

Comment: This is fantastic, add my booking site and it is working very good

Comment: Is it still working for the latest woocommerce version ?

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted LoicTheAztec's answer to work with 2 categories.  It seems to be working.  I did not adapt the text `has_mandatory_categorytext` function, .  If you can follow the code you can diy, but I was focusing on just functionality.  There is another answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431544/checking-that-one-of-multiple-mandatory-products-categories-are-in-cart/40434064#40434064) but I preferred this answer and the other was not working for me.

```
// Function that define the 2 mandatory product categories cat1 & cat2
 function your_mandatory_category_slug(){ $category = 'cat1';    return $category; }
 function your_mandatory_category_slug2(){ $category = 'cat2';    return $category; }
// Conditional function that returns true if the mandatory product category is in cart
function has_mandatory_category1(){
    $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
    $has_cat = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( has_term($category_needed, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $has_cat = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $has_cat;
 }
// Conditional function that returns true if the mandatory product category is in cart
function has_mandatory_category2(){
    $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug2();
    $has_cat = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( has_term($category_needed, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $has_cat = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $has_cat;
 }





// Function that redirect from checkout to mandatory product category archives pages
function mandatory_category_checkout_redirect() {
    // If cart is not empty on checkout page
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_checkout() ){
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
        $category_needed2 = your_mandatory_category_slug2();
        if ( !has_mandatory_category1() )
            wp_redirect( get_term_link( $category_needed, 'product_cat' ) );
        if ( !has_mandatory_category2() )
            wp_redirect( get_term_link( $category_needed2, 'product_cat' ) );
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mandatory_category_checkout_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm for my Wordpress installation with Woocommerce v2.6.12.

I would like to add two mandatory product-categories, maybe 3 or 4 in the future. I tried changing:

```
$category = 'slug1';
```

to

```
$category = 'slug1', 'slug2';
```

and

```
$category = array('slug1','slug2');
```

Without success. Is there a way to make this code work with multiple slugs?

Comment: this is not an answer, but a question.  delete your answer, and open a new question.