# Checking that one of multiple mandatory products categories are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I have to check if one of my two mandatory products categories is in cart.

I have customized the code from this answer: 
[Allow checkout only when a product of a mandatory category is in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644645/allow-checkout-only-when-a-product-of-a-mandatory-category-is-in-cart)

But with my custom code, it always checks for only one of them and I get some errors. My code is not working.

How can I make it work for 2 product categories instead of one?

Here is the code:

```
 // Function that define the mandatory product category
         function your_mandatory_category_slug(){
        // DEFINE HERE the SLUG of the needed product category
            $category = 'cxsuite-download-option';
            return $category;
         }

         function your_mandatory_category_slug_h(){

             // DEFINE HERE the SLUG of the needed product category
            $category_h = 'cxsuite-hosted-option';
            return $category_h;
         }
    // Conditional function that returns true if the mandatory product category is in cart
    function has_mandatory_category(){
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
       $category_needed_h = your_mandatory_category_slug_h();
        $has_cat = false;

        // Iterrating each item in cart and detecting…
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {

            // Detects if the needed product category is in cart items
            if ( has_term($category_needed, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                $has_cat = true;
                break;
            }
            elseif ( has_term($category_needed_h, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                $has_cat = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $has_cat;
     }
// Function that display a message if there is not in cart a mandatory product category
function mandatory_category_display_message() {
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
       $category_needed_h = your_mandatory_category_slug_h();


    // check that cart is not empty (for cart and product category archives)
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( $category_needed ) || is_product_category( $category_needed_h ) ) ){
        $category_needed_single=null;
        if( $category_needed=='cxsuite-download-option' ){
            $category_needed_single='cxsuite-download-option';
        }{
            $category_needed_single=$category_needed_h;
        }
        $category_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_needed_single, 'product_cat' );

        if ( is_wp_error( $category_obj ) ) return;


        // Display message when product category is not in cart items
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() ) {
            $category_name = $category_obj->name;
            $category_url = get_term_link( $category_needed_single, 'product_cat' );

            // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '<strong>Reminder:</strong> You have chosen Addon that can only be purchased together with a %1$s. Please add a %1$s (full or trial) before checking out. Please return <a href="%2$s"> here to "%1$s" product page</a>', 'your_theme_domain'), $category_name, $category_url ), 'error' );

        }

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mandatory_category_display_message', 30 ); // for product mandatory category archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_category_display_message' ); // for cat page


// Function that redirect from checkout to mandatory product category archives pages
function mandatory_category_checkout_redirect() {

    // If cart is not empty on checkout page
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_checkout() ){
        $category_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
        $category_needed_h = your_mandatory_category_slug_h();
        $category_needed_single=null;
        if(is_product_category( $category_needed )){
            $category_needed_single=$category_needed;
        }else{
            $category_needed_single=$category_needed_h;
        }

        // If missing product category => redirect to the products category page
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() )
            wp_redirect( get_term_link( $category_needed_single, 'product_cat' ) );
    }

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mandatory_category_checkout_redirect');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** *(on April 2018)*

You can only use partially the code you have picked up from my answer, for 2 or more categories, using an array of product categories this way:

```
// Function that define the mandatory product category
function your_mandatory_category_slug(){
// DEFINE HERE the 2 SLUGs of the needed product categories
    $categories = array('cxsuite-download-option','cxsuite-hosted-option');
    return $categories;
}

// Conditional function that returns true if the mandatory products categories are in cart
function has_mandatory_category(){
    $categories_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();
    $has_cat = false;

    // Iterrating each item in cart and detecting…
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {

        // iterating both categories
        foreach ( $categories_needed as $category_needed ) {

            // Detects if one of the needed product categories is in cart items
            if ( has_term($category_needed, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) )
                $has_cat = true;
        }
        if($has_cat) 
            break;
    }
    return $has_cat;
}

// Function that display a message if there is not in cart a mandatory product category
function mandatory_category_display_message() {
    $categories_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();

    // check that cart is not empty (for cart and product category archives)
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( $categories_needed[0] ) || is_product_category( $categories_needed[1] ) ) ){
        $category_name = array();
        $category_url = array();

        // iterating both categories
        foreach($categories_needed as $key => $category_needed){
            $category_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_needed, 'product_cat' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $category_obj ) ) 
                return;

            $category_name[$key] = $category_obj->name;
            $category_url[$key] = get_term_link( $category_needed, 'product_cat' );
        }
        // Display message when one of the product categories is not in cart items
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() ) {
            // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '<strong>Reminder:</strong> You have to add in your cart, a product from "%1$s" or from "%3$s" category, to be allowed to check out. Please return <a href="%2$s"> here to "%1$s"</a> or <a href="%4$s"> here to "%3$s"</a> product pages', 'your_theme_domain'), $category_name[0], $category_url[0], $category_name[1], $category_url[1] ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mandatory_category_display_message', 30 ); // for product mandatory category archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_category_display_message' ); // for cart page
```

But you will have to choose for the last function, between one of the 2 product categories for the redirection…

```
// Function that redirect from checkout to mandatory product category archives pages
function mandatory_category_checkout_redirect() {

    // If cart is not empty on checkout page
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_checkout() ){
        $categories_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();

        // If missing product category => redirect to the products category page
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() )
            wp_redirect( get_term_link( $categories_needed[0], 'product_cat' ) ); // or $categories_needed[1]
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mandatory_category_checkout_redirect');
```

This goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is based on this functional answer: 
[Allow checkout only when a product of a mandatory category is in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644645/allow-checkout-only-when-a-product-of-a-mandatory-category-is-in-cart)

It is untested, but it should work…

Comment: Hi thanks it  did the nice job, but  in last function  I changed to redirect back to shop page because  of client  if he cant have one ore the other to chose  I think the better solution was to go to shop page. Thanks again.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I read your other comment to open up a new question. Later I found out you already posted your answer here for more than 1 category slug. This one is not working for me. I get an error on this line: 

`if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( $categories_needed[0] || is_product_category( $categories_needed[1] ) ) ){`

I get the error that there is an unexpected '{'.