# Check that one of multiple mandatory products categories are in Woocommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is a new question with the same requirements that the following answer already given in: 
[Checking that one of multiple mandatory products categories are in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431544/checking-that-one-of-multiple-mandatory-products-categories-are-in-cart/40434064#40434064)

But it does not seem to work for me and I get an error on this line:

```
if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( 
$categories_needed[0] || is_product_category( $categories_needed[1] ) ) 
){
```

> I get the error that there is an **unexpected `{`**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just 2 small mistakes:

1) A missing `;` at the end of `return $categories` so in this updated code:

```
// Function that define the mandatory product category
function your_mandatory_category_slug(){
    // DEFINE HERE the 2 SLUGs of the needed product categories
    $categories = array('cxsuite-download-option','cxsuite-hosted-option');

    return $categories; // <== HERE
}
```

2) An missing closing `)` in `is_product_category( $categories_needed[0]` so in this updated code:

```
// Function that display a message if there is not in cart a mandatory product category
function mandatory_category_display_message() {
    $categories_needed = your_mandatory_category_slug();

    // check that cart is not empty (for cart and product category archives)
    if( !WC()->cart->is_empty() && ( is_cart() || is_product_category( $categories_needed[0] ) || is_product_category( $categories_needed[1] ) ) ){
        $category_name = array();
        $category_url = array();

        // iterating both categories
        foreach($categories_needed as $key => $category_needed){
            $category_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_needed, 'product_cat' );
            if ( is_wp_error( $category_obj ) )
                return;

            $category_name[$key] = $category_obj->name;
            $category_url[$key] = get_term_link( $category_needed, 'product_cat' );
        }
        // Display message when one of the product categories is not in cart items
        if ( !has_mandatory_category() ) {
            // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '<strong>Reminder:</strong> You have to add in your cart, a product from "%1$s" or from "%3$s" category, to be allowed to check out. Please return <a href="%2$s"> here to "%1$s"</a> or <a href="%4$s"> here to "%3$s"</a> product pages', 'your_theme_domain'), $category_name[0], $category_url[0], $category_name[1], $category_url[1] ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'mandatory_category_display_message', 30 ); // for product mandatory category archives pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_category_display_message' ); // for cart page
```

Now it should work without errors…

Comment: Thank you for your time and energy! Implemented it, it works!