# Deny checkout for specific cart items in Woocommerce based on product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, categories

Based on [Allow checkout only when a product of a mandatory category is in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644645/allow-checkout-only-when-a-product-of-a-mandatory-category-is-in-cart) I tried to make my own code sample that Renders a notice and prevents checkout if the cart
only contains products in specific categories. It works on prevention and error notice however on adding other products, it still denies checkout.

```
/**
 * Renders a notice and prevents checkout if the cart
 * only contains products in a specific category
 */
//add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'brown_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category' );

function brown_wc_prevent_checkout_for_category() {

    // set the slug of the category for which we disallow checkout
    $categories = array('drinks','extra-accompaniments');

    foreach ($categories as $category => $value) {
        // get the product category
        $product_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $category, 'product_cat' );

        // sanity check to prevent fatals if the term doesn't exist
        if ( is_wp_error( $product_cat ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // check if this category is the only thing in the cart
        if ( brown_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) ) {

            // render a notice to explain why checkout is blocked
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Please choose atleast one bento.', $category ), 'error' );
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Checks if a cart contains exclusively products in a given category
 * 
 * @param string $category the slug of the product category
 * @return bool - true if the cart only contains the given category
 */
function brown_wc_is_category_alone_in_cart( $category ) {

    //When the cart is empty, remove warning message that I have set for when the snippet takes effect
    if (!WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
        // All the code
        // check each cart item for our category
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            // if a product is not in our category, bail out since we know the category is not alone
            if ( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['data']->id ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // if we're here, all items in the cart are in our category
        return true;

    } else {

        return false;   //  Assume you'd want false here, since the cart is empty

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your code that avoid it to work successfully. Your code and requirements are quiet different, than my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644645/allow-checkout-only-when-a-product-of-a-mandatory-category-is-in-cart).

You will have to set your needed button URL and text for the notice, like the "bento" product category link and button name.

Here is the code:

```
// Conditional function that check if the non mandatory product categories are in all cart items
function has_not_mandatory_category(){
    // DEFINE HERE the your non mandatory product categories (Ids, slugs or names)
    $categories = array('drinks','extra-accompaniments');

    // Iterrating each item in cart and detecting…
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // <== This is the right way (working for product variations too)
        if ( ! has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Display a message and prevent checkout if the non mandatory product categories are not in all cart items
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'prevent_checkout_display_notice' ); // for cart and checkout
function prevent_checkout_display_notice() {
    // DEFINE HERE the return button URL and title
    $button_url = '#';
    $button_title = 'Go there';

    // Display message if the non mandatory product categories are not in all cart items
    if ( has_not_mandatory_category() )
        wc_add_notice(
            sprintf( __( 'Please choose at least one bento. <a class="button" href="%s">%s</a>', 'your_theme_domain'),
                $button_url,
                $button_title
            ), 'error'
        );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works…

> Instead of targeting non mandatory product categories you should do the contrary…

Comment: Thank you so much. This works very well and has leaner code. Ps; I have fewer items to deny checkout than allowing.