# Using Woocommerce product category as condition in an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm a novice when it comes to php and Woocommerce and I borrowed some code from somewhere to add a text after each price.
I put this code in functions.php and it works fine.

But I want to use product category as a condition to determine whether the tex should be displayed or not.

See the following example:

```
if ( "ProductCategoryID == Something") {
    $textafter = '( Ex. Moms )'; //add your text
    return $price . '<span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:10px; color:#E9483F" class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
}
```

Any help me with this condition will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce Product category is a custom taxonomy, you will use the [WordPress conditional function  `has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), this way:

```
if( has_term( array('Something'), 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) )
    $textafter = '( Ex. Moms )'; //add your text 
    return $price . '<span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:10px; color:#E9483F" class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
}
```

Or with the `$product` *(The `WC_Product` object)*:

```
if( has_term( array('Something'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
    $textafter = '( Ex. Moms )'; //add your text 
    return $price . '<span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:10px; color:#E9483F" class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
}
```

Where "Something" is your product category…

> The conditional `has_term()` function will accept product categories IDs, slugs or names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a question, should I replace 'Something' with the written name of the category or is it the ID?

Comment: it worked like a charm and Ive learnt something new. Thank you! :)