# Exclude badge display if product is in certain category in Woocommerce product thumbnail

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I added this code to display the badge in the product thumbnail, and it worked

```
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );    
    global $product;    
    
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        $size = 'woocommerce_thumbnail';
        $image_size = apply_filters( 'single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', $size );       
        $get_image = $product->get_image( $image_size );        
        
        $is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();     
       
        if ( $is_on_sale ) {
            $rrp_price        = (int) $product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price       = (int) $product->get_price();            
            // Greater than
            if ( $rrp_price > $sale_price ) {
                $discount_amount  = $rrp_price - $sale_price;
                $discount_percent =  round( ( $discount_amount / $rrp_price ) * 100, 0 ) . '% Off';
                $get_image        = '<span class="wpd-sale-thumbnail"> <span class="wpd-sale-badge">' . $discount_percent . '</span>' . $get_image . '</span>';
            }
        }
    }
    echo $product ? $get_image : '';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```

CSS

```
span.wpd-sale-badge {
    background: #ef3c5a;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

the question is, is it possible to hide the badge if the product has a category for example "deal"

if possible how

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Just add an extra if condition, which checks for the product category: `if ( has_term( array( 'Something' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )` , put this immediately after `if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {`. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50963409/11987538

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the help
I just tested as you suggested, nothing changed,

Comment: if I put it right after `if ( $is_on_sale ) {`  function badge is only shown for that category,

Comment: I mean hide the badge if there is a product related to that category, 
Did I miss something when I added the code?