# Woocommerce disable the shipping option methods in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

On checkout page, I am trying to disable the shipping method option according to my area postcode. [You can find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJ9Z.png) . I am working on Wordpress and PHP as a backend.

If the postcode doesnot match the area, the shipping method will be disable and the text "" will be shown here. I am using this code:

```
        $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();

        foreach ($packages as $key => $value) {
            $shipping_session = "shipping_for_package_$key";

            unset(WC()->session->$shipping_session);
        }
```

But this code is not working, It will not disable the shipping method option. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a zip codes in the backend?

Comment: Hi @Bhautik, 
Yes, I am getting postcodes from the WordPress admin shipping settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable shipping methods via the [**`woocommerce_package_rates`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-shipping.html#source-view.362) hook.

You can get the **postcode** via the second argument of the hook: `$package`.

In the example below, if the **postcode** doesn't match one of those in the `$postcodes` array, the shipping methods are disabled *(you can also apply your logic in reverse, by exclusion. You can also check the state and country if needed.)*.

All the fields you can get through `$package` are:

- `$package['destination']['country']`
- `$package['destination']['state']`
- `$package['destination']['postcode']`
- `$package['destination']['city']`
- `$package['destination']['address']`
- `$package['destination']['address_1']`
- `$package['destination']['address_2']`

Then:

```
// disable shipping methods based on postcode
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_shipping_method_based_on_postcode', 10, 2 );
function disable_shipping_method_based_on_postcode( $rates, $package ) {

    // initialize postcodes to match
    $postcodes = array( 12050, 20052, 15600, 45063 );

    // if the customer's postcode is not present in the array, disable the shipping methods
    if ( ! in_array( $package['destination']['postcode'], $postcodes ) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
        }
    }
 
    return $rates;
    
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [Disable shipping for specific products based on country in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795558/disable-shipping-for-specific-products-based-on-country-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo, 
I can't use any hook to solve this. As I extended the plugin and getting the postcode from the Wordpress admin side shipping settings. I need to get shipping methods in that PHP file and unset it according to postcodes. 

Thank You.

Comment: Could you publish your complete code necessary to be able to test without using any hooks? I'll do some tests and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo, I have updated the question with my full function. I have to unset the shipping options when the status code of the API doesn't return the 200. Thank You