# Tick a delivery method available to only one city

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code to display the delivery method "local pickup" only for one city (Paris). I use the code together with the plugin "States, Cities, and Places for WooCommerce" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/states-cities-and-places-for-woocommerce/) and everything works correctly.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_package_rates_filter_callback', 100, 2 );

function shipping_package_rates_filter_callback( $rates, $package ) {
 // Define the allowed cities for local pickup
 $allowed_cities = array( 'Paris' );
 // The defined method id
 $pickup_method_id = 'local_pickup:3';

 // Get the shipping city for the current order
 $shipping_city = isset( $package['destination']['city'] ) ? strtolower( $package['destination']['city'] ) : '';

 // Check if the shipping city is in the allowed cities and the pickup method is available
 if ( in_array( $shipping_city, $allowed_cities ) && isset( $rates[$pickup_method_id] ) ) {
     return $rates;
 } else {
     // Hide the pickup method
     unset( $rates[$pickup_method_id] );
     return $rates;
 }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );

function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
 $bool = true;

 // Define the allowed cities for local pickup
 $allowed_cities = array( 'Paris' );

 // Check if the shipping city is in the allowed cities
 $shipping_address = WC()->customer->get_shipping();
 if ( isset( $shipping_address['city'] ) && in_array( strtolower( $shipping_address['city'] ), $allowed_cities ) ) {
     $bool = false;
 }

 // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
 foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
     WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
 }
 WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

My problem is that I would like the "local pickup" delivery method to be checked by default when choosing the city of Paris.Although I put this method in the first position, the default checked method is one of the methods that appears before selecting the city (the one in the 2nd place). I tried to modify the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. How could I solve the problem?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'ahir_select_free_shipping_by_default' );

function ahir_select_free_shipping_by_default() {
    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() )
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );

    // Check if "free shipping" is already set
    if ( strpos( WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0], 'free_shipping' ) !== false )
        return;

    // Loop through shipping methods
    foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $key => $rate ){
        if( $rate->method_id === 'free_shipping' ){
            // Set "Free shipping" method
            WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', array($rate->id) );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set/define the default shipping method when the city is "Paris", try the following that uses `woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method` filter hook:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'set_default_chosen_shipping_method', 10, 3 );
function set_default_chosen_shipping_method( $default, $rates, $chosen_method ){ 
    $allowed_cities = array('Paris');
    $matched_city   = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $key => $package ) {
        if ( isset($package['destination']['city']) 
        && in_array( ucfirst($package['destination']['city']), $allowed_cities ) ) {
            $matched_city = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( ! $matched_city ) {
        return $default;
    }

    // Loop through shipping methods
    foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if( $rate->method_id === 'local_pickup' ){
            return $rate_key;
        }
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work.

---

Note that in your existing code, for the 2 first functions, you should replace `strtolower(` with `ucfirst(` if you want to get it working with the defined city(s).

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_package_rates_callback', 100, 2 );
function shipping_package_rates_callback( $rates, $package ) {
    $pickup_cities  = array('Paris'); // The defined allowed cities
    $pickup_rate_id = 'local_pickup:3'; // The defined method id

    // Get the shipping city for the current order
    $shipping_city = isset($package['destination']['city']) ? ucfirst($package['destination']['city']) : '';

    // Check if the shipping city is in the allowed cities and the pickup method is available
    if ( ! in_array($shipping_city, $pickup_cities) && isset($rates[$pickup_rate_id]) ) {
        unset($rates[$pickup_rate_id]); // Hide the pickup method
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    $pickup_cities  = array('Paris'); // The defined allowed cities
    $bool = true;

    // Check if the shipping city is in the allowed cities
    if ( in_array( ucfirst(WC()->customer->get_shipping_city()), $pickup_cities ) ) {
        $bool = false;
    }
    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( "shipping_for_package_{$package_key}", $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself correctly, but your method doesn't work for me. Anyway, thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: As I don't use old discontinued States, Cities, and Places for WooCommerce plugin, My code is working fine with WooCommerce checkout city field… Also as you didn't provide all your shipping rate IDs and configuration it's difficult to guess things by magic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I did it right, but I found a solution to make it work the way I want. Based on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083089/21533506 I added the following code:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_shipping_method_based_on_location', 10, 2 );
function disable_shipping_method_based_on_location( $rates, $package ) {

    
    $city = $package['destination']['city'];

    // If the city is Paris, hide flat_rate:2, flat_rate:4 and local_pickup:3
    if ( 'Paris' === $city ) {
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:2'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:4'] );
    } else { // Otherwise, hide flat_rate:6, flat_rate:7 and local_pickup:3 for all other localities
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:6'] );
        unset( $rates['flat_rate:7'] );
        unset( $rates['local_pickup:3'] );
    }
 
    return $rates;
```

After that I added the following code to hide all delivery methods until the address is filled in:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_until_address');
function hide_shipping_until_address($rates) {
    $address = WC()->customer->get_shipping();
    $city = isset($address['city']) ? $address['city'] : '';
    $state = isset($address['state']) ? $address['state'] : '';

    if (empty($city) || empty($state)) {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            unset($rates[$rate_id]);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

After that I modified the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77896304/21533506 to display the local fetch in the first position:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $free_shipping_exists = false; // Initialize free shipping flag

    // Loop through shipping rates for the current shipping package
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // If method is free shipping, set free shipping flag to true
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free_shipping_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If free shipping exists, hide other shipping methods except local pickup
    if ( $free_shipping_exists ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // If method is not local pickup and not free shipping, unset it
            if ( 'local_pickup' !== $rate->method_id && 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] );
            }
            // If method is local pickup, set cost to zero
            elseif ( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = array_fill_keys( array_keys( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes ), 0 );
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```